Prevent Windows/RDP from hiding the Language Indicator from the host tray area when an RDP window is active
When an RDP connection to a remote machine is opened, Windows(?)/RDP client(?) automatically hides the language indicator from the host tray area. When the window becomes inactive, the indicator is shown again. When it becomes active, it is again hidden. Is there a way to prevent this behavior and let the host language indicator be always visible?
Seen this behavior in Windows 10.
